# How do I place divs on top of other divs?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place my leftbody and rightbody over top of my MidBody but it doesnt seem to work. I thought placing the Midbody to relative and the left and right bodies to absolute with a z-index would help but it doesnt. So i am clueless right now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```css
    .Header {
      background-color: #CCCCCC;
      width: calc(100%-16px);
      height: 100px;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .MidBody {
      background-color: #141414;
      width: calc(100%-16px);
      height: 850px;
      margin-top: 3px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      position: relative;
    }
    .footer {
      background-color: #CCCCCC;
      width: calc(100%-16px);
      height: 50px;
      margin-top: 5px;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    #leftbody {
      background-color: #F1F1F1;
      width: calc(50%-16px);
      height: 425px;
      float: left;
      margin-left: 3px;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    #rightbody {
      background-color: #F1F1F1;
      width: calc(50%-16px);
      height: 425px;
      float: right;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
    }
```

```html
<div class="Header"></div>
<div class="MidBody">
  <div id="leftbody"></div>
  <div id="rightbody"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Comment: seems like a display:flex; job :) if you mean by top before

Comment: Im new to this still. Where exactly would I place that element?

Comment: this is no element , this is display. but absolute should not be used here, unless you want element on top of each other in same area, could you clarify (my english is not so good ;) )

Comment: Well I want my left body and rightbody side by side inside of my MidBody.

Comment: What do you mean by "leftbody and rightbody over top of my MidBody"?

Comment: I fixed it now. Thank you though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed

```
float:left;  ->  left:0;
float:right;  ->  right:0;
```

and

```
width:calc(50%-16px);  ->   width:50%;
```

**Final css :**

```css
.Header {
background-color:#CCCCCC;
width: calc(100%-16px);
height: 100px;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.MidBody {
background-color:#141414;
width: calc(100%-16px);
height: 850px;
margin-top:3px;
border-radius: 5px;
position: relative;

}

.footer {
background-color:#CCCCCC;
width:calc(100%-16px);
height: 50px;
margin-top: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;

}

#leftbody {
background-color:#F1F1F1;
width:50%;
height:425px;
left:0;
margin-left: 3px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 9999;
}

#rightbody {
background-color:#F1F1F1;
width:50%;
height:425px;
right:0;
position: absolute;
z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<div class="Header"></div>
<div class="MidBody">
  <div id="leftbody"></div>
  <div id="rightbody"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: fixed;` instead of `position: absolute;`